# Can obtain facebook user basic information with ONLY access token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm doing an IOS app with facebook SSO. Upon user granted facebook permission to the app, the app will receive an access token. The app will then make an API call to the backend with ONLY the access token.

So is the backend possible to retrieve basic user information with ONLY access token while the user's facebook id is unknown?

Looking forward to an answer. thank u=)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, once you have a user access token /`me` can be used as a placeholder for the current user's user ID
so `/me/friends` returns the access token user's friends, etc

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug that has been recorded and fixed by Facebook. Update your base_facebook.php to versions 3.2.2.

You can track the bug here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/238039849657148